Question about 5-level scheme to solve wave equation numerically
Consider the wave equation: $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ with initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ and certain boundary conditions, at $x=0$ and $x=L$. If we wanted to solve this PDE numerically, a logical first step would be to apply a 3-level scheme:
$(u_{xx})^n_j=\frac{u^n_{j+1}-2u^n_{j}+u^n_{j-1}}{Δx^2}$ and $(u_{tt})^n_j=\frac{u^{n+1}_{j}-2u^n_{j}+u^{n-1}_{j}}{Δt^2}$, where $j$ is the spatial and $n$ the time index. This discretization would lead to the following scheme:
$u^{n+1}_{j}=\frac{Δt^2}{Δx^2}(u^n_{j+1}+u^n_{j-1})+2(1-\frac{Δt^2}{Δx^2})u^n_j-u^{n-1}_j$  which gives an error of $O(Δt^2)+O(Δx^2)$. From our initial conditions we obtain $u^0_j$ and from the derivative we can obtain $u^1_j$, using a ghost point, supposing we would like to maintain an $O(Δt^2)$ error: $(u_t)^0_j=\frac{u^1_j-u^{-1}_j}{2Δt}=g(jΔx)=g_j$. Solving for $u^{-1}_j$, we can obtain the first time step $u^{1}_j$, if we use the original scheme:
$u^{1}_j=\frac{Δt^2}{2Δx^2}(u^0{j+1}+u^0_{j-1})+(1-\frac{Δt^2}{Δx^2})u^0_j+Δtg_j$.
Suppose now we want to solve the exact same problem by using a 5-level scheme, so in our approximations of the partial derivatives we would use 5 points: 
$(u_{xx})^n_j=\frac{-u^n_{j+2}+16u^n_{j+1}-30u^n_{j}+16u^n_{j-1}-u^n_{j-2}}{12Δx^2}$,
$(u_{tt})^n_j=\frac{-u_j^{n+2}+16u_j^{n+1}-30u_j^{n}+16u_j^{n-1}-u_j^{n-2}}{12Δx^2}$,
from which we would get some recurrence relation. My question is, what would the procedure be to determine the first three time steps, from the initial conditions, in order to apply the scheme correctly?

This is typically done by applying some higher-order single step time-stepping scheme for the first few time steps until you have enough to use your multistep method. High order Runge-Kutta methods are a reasonable choice, however you must be careful to choose an implicit method as your problem is very stiff and could likely lead explicit methods to become unstable without heavily restricting the step size. It is also important that the order of the starting method is higher than your method so that you do not introduce too much error to the initial points for your multistep method.

Thank you for your answer! Could you provide any sources?
